# How to add a method to Observable trait?

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, observable, rx-scala

I would like to add a method to the `Observable` class. What I have done so far was:

```
object Extension {

implicit class ObservableExtensions(obs: Observable[Double]) extends Observable{

    def fakeMethod (alpha: Double): Observable[Double] = {
      obs
        .map(v => v+alpha) 
      }

    }

 }
```

But I get:

```
Error: trait Observable takes type parameters
implicit class ObservableExtensions(obs: Observable[Double]) extends Observable{
                                                                   ^
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

manish is  true in that Observable actually isn't just a trait, it is a parametrized trait. That means you must supply it a type parameter in order to turn it into a trait you can actually extend (like in `class Foo extends Observable[Double]`, where you turn a parametrized trait `Observable` into a trait `Observable[Double]` and then extend class `Foo` with it.

zxswing has already said it, you don't need to extends Observable at all. Just do a

```or-tag-here
import rx.lang.scala.Observable

object Extension {
  implicit class ObservableExtensions(obs: Observable[Double]) {
    def fakeMethod(alpha: Double): Observable[Double] = obs.map(_+alpha) 
  }
}  

import Extension._
Observable
    .just(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
    .fakeMethod(10)
    .subscribe(println, println, println)
```

see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html for reference.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to `extends Observable`. `implicit` will still work without `extends Observable`.

Answer (score 3):

The class [rx.Observable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java) takes a generic type parameter, which your code does not supply, hence the error.

It should probably be `extends Observable[Double]`.